# unable to change default language in codeigniter admin panel

Tags: codeigniter

I need to chang my default english language to german in codeigniter. I changed in application/config.php laguage as german. but the default language not change. Also i have file into language/de folder with translated content. Then i don't know what i do next for correct output. Can anyone help me?

```
$config['language'] = 'german';
$config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';
```

And Also we have langauage_code is de in my session.

this is my language translated code for example:

```
$lang['signup']='Anmelden'; 
$lang['header_login']='Anmeldung'; 
$lang['footer_follow_help']='Hilfe'; 
$lang['list_your']='Mieten Sie Ihren Platz'; 
$lang['facebook_signup']='Weiter mit Facebook'; 
$lang['signup_google']='Fahren Sie mit Google fort';
.
.
.
```

In my site front end changing only select german. but my back end not chaging. I need to make it as default langage is german.

Comment: where you save lang files?

Comment: How are you displaying text in backend? Please show a piece of code from view file of admin panel.

Comment: Some thing like this http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/language.html#sample-language-files